# JWT Token nested in the "idp_access_token" Claim of the B2C token

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

My project is a MVC Core 3.1 web application.
The autentication is based on the **Microsoft.identity.web** template to sign-in users in Azure AD B2C.

You can find the samples here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki#samples

Users can register/login as standard users on B2C or login with the corporate account (azure AD, so an openID Connect Identity Provider).

When Users signs in with the corporate account, I get a JWT token with a claim named *"idp_access_token"* which contains the access_token from Azure AD. It contains some claims I need for the application (for some reasons I can't even see the emailAddress/unique_name in the B2C token so I need to get it from here...).

But I'm not sure how (and where) I'm supposed to deal with this token and how to access the claims inside it. Can I map them in the claimPrincipal? Because I would like to use the email as the "User.identity.name".
Should I write a service (transient?) and Inject it where I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a feature you don’t actually need. Usually the embedded IdP access token is used to call the services that the IdP hosts. For example, a user logs in with Facebook and your app wants to call the Facebook API to post to their Facebook wall.

You as the app developer should not inspect or use the token for your own self, as you cannot trust it. If you want data from that token, then perform the relevant claims mappings in your B2C policy/user flow, as B2C does validate the token and can trust it. You cannot. Services provided by the IdP will verify it, so also can trust it.